# A click that is supposed to work on only one thing affects all

Tags: javascript

I made a circle that's supposed to disappear when it's clicked, but for some reason when I click on it, everything on the screen disappears, or if I click on any other thing on the screen, that also makes everything disappear. Here's my code for the circle (minus the css which makes the div into a circle). The full code is in the link.

```
<div id="circle"> <div>
```

---

```
document.getElementById("circle").onclick = function()  {
            document.getElementById("circle").style.display="none";
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Dovid_M/51smpyeq/#&togetherjs=gAo0i0hlSt

Comment: Why get the element twice? Why not use `this`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in your JSFiddle was inside a div with `id="circle"`. That was because you were missing a `/` in the closing `</div>`.

If browsers would throw an error instead of attempting to render invalid HTML you would've spotted the problem right away.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you didn't close your `div` tag correctly.

Its `<div id="circle"> </div>`, not `<div id="circle"> <div>`.

Because you didn't put the `/` in the closing tag, Javascript thought your tag never ended and simply thought everything else after it was also part of `<div id="circle">`.